# Keyboard layout shortcut

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

I've changed my kb layout using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` because I need to use Russian keys in TTY.

It changed my shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and changed my <kbd>Super</kbd> key so it's now <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. So I cannot use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to change my layout (with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>)

How to change it back?

BTW I'm using Ubuntu-gnome
and I still want to change keyboard layout on TTY, where <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> do not work.

Contents of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

EDIT: I have to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` every time I log in to make my <kbd>Super</kbd> key work as <kbd>Super</kbd> key, because it always acts like <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>

Comment: Please show us the contents of the `/etc/default/keyboard` file by editing your question.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, and deleted my answer. Hopefully somebody else is able to help.